# Como solucionar la carga lenta de un slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

Estoy utilizando un slider de slick, en una tab, al momento de presionar la tab, empieza a cargar el contenido del slider, cuando me voy a otra tab y vuelvo a donde esta el slider, vuelve a cargar el slider como si se inicializara desde 0.
Estaba pensando en 2 soluciones

1. Cargar el contenido de la tab playlist desde que se abre la pagina (pero esto no se como se hace)
2. Poner un loader para que cuando termine de cargar el slider no se muestre de esa forma

Pero el slider no me carga de manera correcta cuando le doy click a la tab, no se oculta y se queda estático

Asi se muestra el slider al cargarse

[image: Error]

Asi es como se debe de ver

[image: Success]

Este es mi codigo

```
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('../../img/gif1.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
     <div id="loader" class="loader">Cargando...</div>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.onload= function(){ 
            var loud= document.getElementById('loader');
            
            loud.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
            loud.style.opacity = "0"; 
        };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una tercera solución y es cargar desde un principio la estructura final que tendrá, esta librería tiene la peculiaridad de cargar poco a poco los recursos, asi que yo busque las propiedades finales y se las agregue a la estructura inicial de carga

```
        .slick-slider {
            width: 243%;
        }
.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-width: 2093px;

}
```

No fue necesario un loader, pero igual y es una solución viable